# Proper use of the strcmp function?

Tags: c, strcmp

Can someone please explain to me how to properly use the `strcmp` function? I'm creating a tic-tac-toe game and I keep getting the error:

```
passing argument 1 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

I've created two pointers that act as parameters for the `strcmp` function. One is the input that the player puts in, the second is the selection of moves the player has. However, when I try to run the code I get the error above. Below is a piece of my code:

```
void mark_location(int userU, char str) {
    char *moves[] = {"upperLeft", "up", "upperRight", "left", "center", "right", "lowerLeft", "down", "lowerRight"};

    if (strcmp(str, moves[0]) == 0)
        board[0][0] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[1]) == 0)
        board[0][1] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[2]) == 0)
        board[0][2] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[3]) == 0)
        board[1][0] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[4]) == 0)
        board[1][1] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[5]) == 0)
        board[1][2] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[6]) == 0)
        board[2][0] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[7]) == 0)
        board[2][1] = userU;
    else if (strcmp(str, moves[8]) == 0)
        board [2][2] = userU;
}
```

Comment: `mark_location(int userU, char *str)`

Comment: The error has to do with your type. However, there are some problems with your choice of determining which move to pick (for example, what should happen if an invalid move is selected?). Do you think you could turn the strings into an enum and then run a switch statement?

Answer (score 4):

As others have already pointed out, the second argument should be of type `char*` and not `char`.

I just wanted to mention that the series of `if` statements can be rewritten as a `for` loop:

```
void mark_location(int userU, char* str) {
    char *moves[] = {"upperLeft", "up", "upperRight", "left", "center", "right", "lowerLeft", "down", "lowerRight"};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (strcmp(str, moves[i]) == 0) {
            board[i / 3][i % 3] = userU;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

It may also be worth considering whether it makes sense to re-initialize `moves` every time the function is called, and whether an invalid value of `str` should raise an error.

Answer (score 3):

Change your function declaration to the following:

```
void mark_location(int userU, char *str) {
```

Note the change from `char` (a single character) to `char *` (a string).

Also make sure you have included `string.h` at the top of your file:

```
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error and it says that I'm using the * operator wrong.

Comment: I put the * exactly where you told me, before the str. Still getting the same message and I included string.h

Answer (score 1):

In the function arguments, you have declared "str" as "char". It should be "char*".

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` expects a pointer to an array of characters, but `str` is declared as a single character, when it should be `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (!strcmp(*str, *moves[i]) ) {
        board[i / 3][i % 3] = userU;
        break;
    }
}
```

One more thing for saving typing effort:

`strcmp()` returns 0 when strings match so while writing that in a control statement prefer writing

```
if(!strcmp(hello, world)){/* do this do that*/}.....1
```

instead of writing

```
if(strcmp(hello, world)==0){/* do this do that*/}......2
```

in the first equation the if statement does the NOT of whatever `strcmp` returns to it so if the strings are equal you'll get a 0 and NOT 0 is a 1

So it works saving tons of your time typing.